# How do I create a JPG preview of a PDF (using the Linux command line)?

Tags: linux, pdf, image-processing, jpeg, preview

I'm trying to find a method of converting a PDF to high quality JPG previews on a linux box.

I'm currently using ImageMagicK + GhostScript but I have to supersample the images so much to get readable quality that it takes forever to process (30+ seconds on my box for one page).

Does anyone know of a better method where I can achieve high quality previews without having to supersample so much?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if a Java product will suit your needs but this article - [Convert PDF To High-Resolution Images Using Java](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=135&t=Convert_PDF_To_High-Resolution_Images_Using_Java) - was written for our product Gnostice PDFOne.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I can't fork out 500 bucks. :(

Answer (score 8):

I found **pdftoppm** installed on my Ubuntu Linux box.

```
pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 -scale-to 1024 -png input-file.pdf output-file
```

- The output is high-quality when **-scale-to** px is large
- The conversion is quite fast
- My command above creates a preview for just the first page (**-f 1 -l 1**)
- Output-file seems to be of the format: *output-file-1.png* (where 1 is the page number)

Comment: And if you have to work with a platform where all packages are at least five years old \*cough*CentOS*cough\*, `pdftoppm` won’t know about the `-scale-to` or `-png` options, so you use the `-r` option instead, let it convert to ppm, and then use ImageMagick to convert from ppm to PNG.

Answer (score 0):

First you convert your pdf to ps using `pdf2ps` command

`pdf2ps file.pdf file.ps`

Then you can further process the output to jpg using ImageMagick's convert

`convert -resample 300 file.ps file.jpg`

Comment: this is probably what you tried, I was just guessing, because you didn't include your attempt.

Comment: I haven't tried converting the images to PS first. I will try and see if it makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to reduce quality and increase processing time.